# condition check on scanf ()or get on input

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

I have to print first, middle and last name in abbreviation from a full-name input from from user,e.g `ram kumar shahu` as `r.k. shahu`.Problem is that if I get only first name and last name then I should print like `r. shahu`.

Below is my code so far.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        char fname[10],mname[10],lname[10];
        printf("Enter the name:\n");
        if(lname==NULL)
        {
           scanf("%s %s ",fname,mname);
        }
        else
            scanf("%s %s %s",fname,mname,lname);
        if(lname==NULL)
        {
            printf("%c.%s",fname[0],mname);
        }
        else
            printf("%c.%c.%s",fname[0],mname[0],lname);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: spoiler: `if(lname==NULL)` is always false.

Comment: what i do if  get only first name and middle name so how i print middle name full

Comment: Is this code written by you? is there any reason 'if(lname==NULL)' line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char fname[10],mname[10],lname[10];
char line[30];
int state;

printf("Enter the name:\n");
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
state = sscanf(line, "%9s %9s %9s", fname, mname, lname);
if(state == 2){
    printf("%c.%s\n",fname[0], mname);
} else if(state == 3){
    printf("%c.%c.%s\n",fname[0], mname[0], lname);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: nice...really it good to use.that is exactly what i wanna do.thanks

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you are dealing with a case where you don't know the *length* of the input. I would suggest you to take the following approach.

1. Read the whole input from user using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. Start tokenizing based on fixed delimiter , maybe a space. You can use [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)
3. If token count is 2, the tokens are considered as first and last name
4. If token cout is 3, they are first, middle and last names.
5. Then, you can print out the first element from all the tokens required (1 or 2). That is, in case 3, you print the first element of the first token and the complete second token, in case of 4, you print the first elements from first and second token and the third in full.